# Add custom restriction of folders in Plone

Tags: python, plone

Can I add a custom restriction for the folder contents in Plone 4.1. Eg. Restrict the folder to contain only files with extensions like *.doc, *.pdf
I am aware of the general restrictions like file/ folder/ page / image which is available in Plone

Answer (score 1):

Not without additional development; you'd have to extend the File type with a validator to restrict the mime types allowed.

Without going into the full detail (try for yourself and ask more questions here on SO if you get stuck), here are the various moving parts I'd implement if I were faced with this problem:

1. Create a new `IValidator` class to check for allowed content types:

   ```
   from zope.interface import implements
   from Products.validation.interfaces.IValidator import IValidator

   class LocalContentTypesValidator(object):
       implements(IValidator)

       def __init__(self, name, title='', description='')
           self.name = name
           self.title = title or name
           self.description = description

       def __call__(value, *args, **kwargs):
           instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)
           field    = kwargs.get('field', None)

           # Get your list of content types from the aq_parent of the instance
           # Verify that the value (*usually* a python file object)
           # I suspect you have to do some content type sniffing here

           # Return True if the content type is allowed, or an error message
   ```
2. Register an instance of your validotor with the register:

   ```
   from Products.validation.config import validation
   validation.register(LocalContentTypesValidator('checkLocalContentTypes'))
   ```
3. Create a new subclass of the ATContentTypes ATFile class, with a copy of the baseclass schema, to add the validator to it's validation chain:

   ```
   from Products.ATContentTypes.content.file import ATFile, ATFileSchema

   Schema = ATFileSchema.schema.copy()
   Schema['file'].validators = schema['file'].validators + (
       'checkLocalContentTypes',)

   class ContentTypeRestrictedFile(ATFile):
       schema = Schema
       # Everything else you need for a custom Archetype
   ```

   or just alter the ATFile schema itself if you want this to apply to all File objects in your deployment:

   ```
   from Products.ATContentTypes.content.file import ATFileSchema

   ATFileSchema['file'].validators = ATFileSchema['file'].validators + (
       'checkLocalContentTypes',)
   ```
4. Add a field to Folders or a custom sub-class to store a list of locally allowed content types. I'd probably use [`archetypes.schemaextender`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/archetypes.schemaextender) for this. There is plenty of documentation on this these days, [`WebLion has a nice tutorial`](http://weblion.psu.edu/services/documentation/developing-for-plone/products-from-scratch/schemaextender) for example.

   You'd have to make a policy decision on how you let people restrict mime-types here of course; wildcarding, free-form text, a vocabulary, etc.